# Add menu item with SpannableString

Tags: android

I add SpannableString to menu item as item name, but after clicking on this menu I get the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid payload item type
        at android.util.EventLog.writeEvent(Native Method)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2306)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:830)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:160)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:885)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:545)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How can I fix this problem ? Is it possible to add SpannableString to menu item ?

Comment: Is there another way to change menu item text style ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Overriding, **onMenuItemSelected** and instead of

**return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item).** use **return true**